# How do I calculate the exact number of real roots for a polynomial?

Tags: functions, roots, graphing-functions

So, for example, if I had a polynomial of order $5$, such as $$(10x^5  -3x^3 + 120x - 30) = 0$$ how would I figure out exactly how many real roots it has?

I understand that it can have maximum $5$ real roots, and it can have $3$ or $1$ real roots, as complex numbers come in conjugate pairs however I cannot figure out how to the exact number.

I would need to do this without a calculator.

Thank you.

EDIT: Apologies, I gave the wrong powers, this has now been amended

Comment: This polynomial is of order $3$ . It would have $3$ roots.

Comment: Have you tried using [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)?

Comment: See [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

Comment: As an aside, it feels particularly strange to me to see a polynomial written with terms not in either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing order... Many people's eyes might be drawn to the first term written and say, "oh, the power is two so it is a quadratic... there is no need for me to read the rest of the terms to verify that."  Also, "polynomial of order *five*"?  What you wrote is a cubic, not a quintic.

Comment: These are the roots in approximative form $$\{\{x\to -0.912138-2.71211 i\},\{x\to -0.912138+2.71211 i\},\{x\to 0.248812\},\{x\to
   4.9088\}\}$$

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong powers but I have fixed it now. Sorry again.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit How many *real* roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^2$$f(x)=10x^5-3x^3+120x-30\implies f'(x)=50x^4-9x^2+120= 50y^2-9y+120>0,$$ as $B^2<4AC.~$
So this polynomial is an increasing function it can have at most one real root. Also it being  odd ordered $f(-\infty)<0, f(\infty)>0$. So by intermediate value theorem it will have one real root. So the given polynomial equation ha only one real root.

Comment: You copy wring the polynomial. The highest degree is 5

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio The original question text had a mistake of the first term using $x^3$ instead of $x^5$.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan oh, then I'm sorry

Comment: Thank you for this, and sorry again for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have a general method: *Sturm's algorithm*, based on this result:

> Let $P$ be a polynomial in $\mathbf R[x]$. Define a (finite) sequence of polynomials $P_n$ with
>   $$P_0=P,\quad P_1=P',\qquad P_i=-(P_{i-2}\bmod P_{i-1})\quad(i\ge 2)$$
>   As the degrees are decreasing, we'll ultimately obtain the null polynomial.The sequence stops at the last nonzero polynomial $P_m$.
>
> Let $[a,b]$ an interval such that $P(a)$ and $P(b)\ne 0$, and denote  $\sigma(\xi)$ the number of changes of sign in the sequence $P(\xi), P_1(\xi), P_2(\xi),\dots, P_m(\xi)$. The number of *distinct* real roots of $P$ in the interval $[a,b]$ is equal to 
>   $$\sigma(a)-\sigma(b).$$

You also have to find bounds for the roots. If the polynomial is, explicitly, 
$$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0\qquad(a_n\ne 0),$$
a rough bound is
$$\max\biggl(1,\frac{|a_0|+|a_1|+\dots+|a_{n-1}|+|a_n|}{|a_n|}\biggr).$$